# For questions closed for failure to meet a guideline, can we show which guideline was violated in the reopen queue?

Tags: discussion, reopen-review

When reviewing closed questions for re-opening, if the original close reason was "This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.", the guideline that was not met is not displayed. This makes it harder to review these questions since there is no way to know if the original close reason was resolved without clicking through to the original post. Can we display the full close reason in the "This question was initially closed as:" message in the queue?

Here's a screenshot showing that the reason is displayed, but the specific guideline is not if the reason was that it did not meet a guideline:
[image]

Comment: The closed reason is shared. What other information are you expecting or need to determine if an edit has addressed the reason a question was closed?

Comment: A communities guidelines are specified in their help center.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you need the original close reason when to re-open you need to confirm that question is suitable to be open on the site in its current state (focused, on-topic, non-duplicate,...)? Since you hopefully know that we don't re-open questions just because close reason is not 100% accurate it really should not matter what the close  reason is for the purposes of re-opening.

Comment: It is largely because of the first menu item, "Original close reasons were not resolved", which I feel like I have to evaluate every time I choose to keep a question closed. It feels strange to either be forced never to choose that menu item for SO guideline violations, or to always click through to the details for them.

Comment: The editing checkbox's label "The original close reason(s) was not resolved" is poor ^ does not reflect when to check the box. The box should be checked when/iff the originally flagged reasons and every other closing reason has been addressed, ie when/iff all closing criteria have been satisfied. It doesn't matter what the original reasons were.

Answer (score 5):

The decision of whether or not to reopen a question should be based solely on the question's *current* contents, not on its edit history, the original close reason, the poster's history, or anything else.

When I visit the reopen queue and see a question, I ask myself: Would *I* have closed this question in its current form? If the answer is "yes", then I will leave the question closed. Even if the stated close reason is different than the one I would have used (maybe it was closed as "Needs debugging details" whereas I would've been inclined to use "Needs more focus", for instance), I'll leave it closed. If the answer is "no", then I will vote to reopen.

Occasionally, looking at the edit history or other details can provide additional *context* for why a question was closed, but this should be the exception rather than the rule (hence, it should require additional effort on the reviewer's part). Generally speaking, content should be judged based on solely that: the *content*, not what it used to look like or why people *originally* thought it was a poor fit for the site.

Comment: Although I don't really disagree with your overall assessment, I think it can be very important to distinguish actual close reasons **in some cases**. One that springs to mind is whether it was closed for "needs debugging details" or "caused by a typo". That difference can often influence my decision on whether or not to reopen a question.

Comment: I don't disagree with this, but since "original close reasons were not resolved" is the first option for why a question should remain closed, I feel forced to click through to the details to find the close reason - as a rule, not as an exception. I'm not entirely opposed to removing that menu option, but having the option and then not displaying the reasons for me to evaluate whether they were resolved feels weird.

Answer (score 5):

Showing the *full* reason for closure in the Reopen Votes review queue would, IMHO, be useful – but it may have been omitted to minimize the space usage of the displayed banner (thus making more of the actual post visible in the default view).

However, for questions closed for such "guideline violations", you can generally see what the *actual* reason was by opening the post in a new window: this will distinguish between, for example, "Needs debugging details" and "Caused by a typo...".

I have no more Reopen Reviews left to me on the main site, today, so maybe [this Meta review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30915) will demonstrate; the review just shows:

> **Not suitable for this site** This question doesn’t meet a Meta Stack Overflow guideline.

However, clicking on the question's title opens a new window, in which the *full* close banner is displayed, revealing that the close voters considered that:

> This question **does not appear to seek input and discussion** from
> the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, …

---

I believe showing the actual/full reason for closure is important because – although I agree with what others have said in terms of not wanting to reopen a question simply to close it for another reason – we now have to specify *why* we think a question should remain closed: We are presented with a second popup asking if we think *"The original close reason(s) was not resolved"*, or if we would rather specify a different reason.

So, how can we agree that the original close reason is still valid if we aren't told what that reason is?